# Properly formatted table throw error for DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, datatables

We are using the [Datatables Bootstrap 4](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4) library to format our tables. Even when we have properly formatted tables, we are still getting the following error message after the page has loaded.

I have added the JS and HTML below, but the code is available on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/userrj/pen/mvGNMG) as well.

- The code on codepen was updated (2/14/2018) to reflect the solution, which was to have all tables have an `<thead>` if one or more require it on a single page.

How do we resolve the error message?

**Goal**

1. All tables inside the `.enable-dt` element, should have `DataTable` enabled
2. We are trying to replicate the [Multiple tables](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multiple_tables.html) functionality.

> Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
    $('.enable-dt table').addClass('table table-striped table-bordered nowrap');
    $('.enable-dt table').DataTable({
        'paging': false,
        'searching': false,
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" media="all">
<div class="enable-dt">
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js" defer=""></script>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Synergistically envisioneer.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Continually utilize client-focused.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Conveniently procrastinate</td>
            </tr>
        <tbody>
    </table>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Completely architect.</td>
                <td>Quickly incubate global</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Seamlessly transform.</td>
                <td>ethical e-services</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Efficiently develop customer directed</td>
                <td>high-yield users</td>
            </tr>
        <tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Per an OP update, the proper table format for datatables requires each table to have a thead. The first table is missing the thead. You will want to add the appropriate thead to the first table.

```
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

Comment: I have updated the question to include goals so it is more clear. See [Multiple tables](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multiple_tables.html) example.

Comment: @usernameabc in the multiple tables examples, both tables have thead, but your first one doesn't. Have you tried adding that in there?

Comment: when i add the `<thead>`, it does resolve the issue. Can you update your answer to reflect this so it doesn't get lost in the comments? I will mark it appropriately afterwards.

Comment: @usernameabc I have updated the answer to only include the thead.